# Update Attributes Error Unknown modifier: $pushAll (9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid6

When I execute update Attributes in my model `update_attributes prod_id: 34978273492`, it returns `Unknown modifier: $pushAll (9)`.

What is the root cause. 
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB 3.6 the deprecated $pushAll operator was removed, see for more details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#remove-pushall-update-operator). If updating `mongoid` to the latest version doesn't solve the problem, the only solution is to downgrade your Mongo version to 3.4.X

Comment: How can I downgrade mongo to 3.4

Comment: You can download previous versions from here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#previous